# My Lubuntu 16.04 system randomly doesn't turns on

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu

I am workng with Lubuntu 16.04 in an old computer and I have a problem with the booting system.

When I turn on the computer, it randomly keeps booting during an interval of time (between 5 and 45 min), even other times it runs perfectly.
I've tried repairing GRUB, reinstalling Lubuntu, running it in recovery mode... and nothing seems to work.

I would like to know if there is a way to know what the computer is loading on boot to see where is the break point, or any other solution to this problem.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean that the system fails to boot occasionally and then immediately reboots the machine to start over? Could you please [edit] your question to clarify that? Thanks.

Comment: No, just freezes until the login appears. With the answer I gave, everything load correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I just got with something that made it work it out.

Just displayed the GRUB. In the `/etc/default/grub` changed the value of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to empty and ran `sudo update-grub`

I don't have anymore quiet booting, but runs every single time